# $_SERVER deprecated, how to $_GET http_referer?

Tags: php, http, header, get, deprecated

After searching and trying to code around the issue, I am going to ask it here.

I am trying to code in accordance with the php manual, and would like to avoid to use deprecated functions.

Which raises my question, how do I get http_referer via $_GET superglobal?

In case you're wondering, I am trying to obfuscate an a header() to be replied only if a session is currently active with HTTP_referer variable defined.

Comment: http_referer is very unreliable, don't use it for anything 'sensitive'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`$_SERVER` is **not** deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php $_SERVER is not deprecated, only $HTTP_SERVER_VARS is. That said, you are free to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 0):

### `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is deprecated, `$_SERVER` is not!

`$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

`$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. (Note that $HTTP_SERVER_VARS and $_SERVER are different variables and that PHP handles them as such)